# SmtpClient.SendAsync function never receive callback and connection is not disposed

Tags: c#, email, smtp

We use SmtpClient.SendAsync to send e-mails asynchronously. 
Here’s full source code SendAsync and SendCompletedCallback

```
SmtpClient m_SmtpClient = null;
MailMessage m_MailMessage = null;

 public void SendAsync(string subject, string body)
        {
            try
            {
                m_SmtpClient = new SmtpClient(SMTPHost, Convert.ToInt32(SMTPPort));
                m_SmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                m_SmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SMTPEmailFrom, SMTPPassword);
                m_SmtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);

                m_MailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(SMTPEmailFrom, SMTPEmailTo, subject, body);
                m_SmtpClient.SendAsync(m_MailMessage, null);
                log.InfoFormat("SENDING ASYNC E-MAIL to {0} {1},{2}", SMTPEmailTo, subject, body);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                log.ErrorFormat(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            String token = (string)e.UserState;

            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                log.InfoFormat("[{0}] Send canceled.", token);
            }
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                log.ErrorFormat("[{0}] {1}", token, e.Error.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                log.InfoFormat("SENDING ASYNC E-MAIL: COMPLETED");
            }
            m_MailMessage.Dispose();
            m_SmtpClient.Dispose(); 
        }
```

The program allows to send 30-40 e-mails and after that stop working.
It was confirmed using Wireshark sniffer that the SMTP Server accepts the TCP connection but never sends the SMTP 220 message.
On the client site we never receive callback and not to be able to dispose the existing smpt client object. After this situation the smpt client cannot send any e-mail until we re-start the program.

1. Is it any way how to handle this scenario and improve recovery mechanism?
2. Is it possible to setup a timeout to break the connection after X seconds?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you able to see a consistent/similar log whenever the message isn't sent, but the connection remains open?  Re: #2 - Yes, of course, you could implement some sort of timeout method, but the problem may not be fully resolved.

Comment: If the program goes to this 'blocking' state, I not able to see any messages between Smtp Client and Smtp Server even I try to send more e-mails using a different instance of  Smtp Client. The program stays in the 'blocking' state until it's restarted.

Comment: The question was, what is the last 'log' file entry?  You're logging exceptions, errors, and successes.  Are your logs containing any exceptions?

Comment: The last log was 'SENDING ASYNC E-MAIL to 'aaa@bbb.com', 'ccc'. There is no any exception. Silence.

Comment: @IouriChametka I seem to have the same problem, sometimes after a few hundred e-mails then after more than one thousand. Did you ever find a solution or workaround to the problem?